Terraform and Azure: Problems with association between NetworkSecurityGroups and Subnets
While applying my terraform script, I'm getting the following error:
╷
│ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/rg-subnet-test/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnet-test-vnet/subnets/subnet-test-subnet" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" for more information.
│
│   with azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.association1,
│   on main.tf line 47, in resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "association1":
│   47: resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "association1" {
│
╵

This is my script:
# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_subnet_test" {
  location = "germanywestcentral"
  name     = "rg-subnet-test"
}

# VNET
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet_subnet_test" {
  address_space       = ["10.100.2.0/24"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.location
  name                = "subnet-test-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.name
}

# Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_germany" {
  name                 = "subnet-test-subnet"
  address_prefixes     = ["10.100.2.0/24"]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_subnet_test.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_subnet_test.name
}

# First Network Security Group
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "app_server_nsg_1" {
  name                = "subnet-test-nsg-1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.name
}

# Second Network Security Group
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "app_server_nsg_2" {
  name                = "subnet-test-nsg-2"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.name
}

# Association between first NSG to subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "association1" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet_germany.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.app_server_nsg_1.id
}

# Association between second NSG to subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "association2" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet_germany.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.app_server_nsg_2.id
}

I don't understand the error, because I only create the subnet once. Why is the second association trying to create the subnet again? What am I doing wrong here?

See moving resources.

No, this is not it. Even if I have a clean slate in Azure this error will be thrown.

If you created the resource(s) using terraform and then moved it you need to manipulate the state file and/or use the move block, as mentioned in the subarticles in the link I've posted. Try removing the correspondent entry from the state and then use the import command, as mentioned in the error message.

Again, this error gets thrown even if I use a completely clean Azure subscription. I'm not moving anything.

I edited my question. I hope that I could demonstrate the problem a bit better now.

The problem was, that I was associating multiple Network Security Groups to one and the same subnet resource. This is apparently not possible, you'll have to create a subnet for each Network Security Group.
A correct example using the code in my question would be (notice the changed address space in the VNET and the additional subnet):
# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_subnet_test" {
  location = "germanywestcentral"
  name     = "rg-subnet-test"
}

# VNET
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet_subnet_test" {
  address_space       = ["10.100.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.location
  name                = "subnet-test-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.name
}

# Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
  name                 = "subnet-test-subnet1"
  address_prefixes     = ["10.100.2.0/24"]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_subnet_test.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_subnet_test.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet2" {
  name                 = "subnet-test-subnet2"
  address_prefixes     = ["10.100.3.0/24"]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_subnet_test.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet_subnet_test.name
}

# First Network Security Group
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "app_server_nsg_1" {
  name                = "subnet-test-nsg-1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.name
}

# Second Network Security Group
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "app_server_nsg_2" {
  name                = "subnet-test-nsg-2"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_subnet_test.name
}

# Association between first NSG to subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "association1" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet1.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.app_server_nsg_1.id
}

# Association between second NSG to subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "association2" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet2.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.app_server_nsg_2.id
}



Terraform and Azure: Problems with association between NetworkSecurityGroups and Subnets

As mentioned in the error we need to import the subnet resource as per the requirement as this only the approach which works. When I test this configuration, I face the similar issue you mentioned

terraform_move command was won't work here as we need move the configuration changes as per the resource we need to move in the state file as Rui Jarimba mentioned it better remove the resource info from the state and reimport it as per the requirement only works as expected.
The error we are faced only due to miss match of configuration with the state which we tried not with the way the resources are provisioned.
Configuration goes as per the repo you shared in github I only shared the part of the configuration where we import the resource.
configuration:
modules/german/main.tf
variable "region" {}
variable "resource_group_name" {}

module "network" {
  source = "../network"
  region = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

module "appserver" {
  source = "../vm/app"
  region = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id = module.network.subnet_id
}

module "dbserver" {
  source = "../vm/db"
  region = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id = module.network.subnet_id
}

modules/network/main.tf:
variable "region" {}
variable "resource_group_name" {}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "subnet-test-de-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = var.region
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "subnet-test-de-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

output "subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
}

continue with the rest of the configuration
Deployment:
run the command  terraform state list

remove the resource

this resource was imported into different module as per the requirement
terraform import 'module.german_region.module.dbserver.azurerm_subnet_network_security_gassociation.association_subnet_db




Refer:
https://github.com/azurerm/terraform-azure-resources/tree/v1.0.10/modules/subnet_network_security_group_association
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet_network_security_group_association
https://github.com/Azure/terraform-azurerm-network-security-group

Thank you for your time, Vinay. I'm still not getting it, why I should run this script, remove the subnet from the state and then re-import it? There has to be a better way to associate two network security groups in one resource group to one subnet?

I edited my question. I hope that I could demonstrate the problem a bit better now.

I now know what I did wrong. I assumed I need a NSG for each Virtual Machine. And I assumed that I can only have one subnet ressource for each NSG. That is wrong. One can only associate one subnet to one NSG. If you try to associate the already used subnet to a different NSG, this error happens.


Error: A resource with the ID xxxxxx already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State.

There are several possible scenarios that can lead to this error:

Resource was created manually and was later added to Terraform configuration: Since Terraform's state does not include this resource, Terraform attempts to create it.
Resource was moved between modules: Terraform loses track of the resource's state because its address has changed and consequently tries to create a new resource with the same ID.
Resource was renamed: Renaming a resource in the configuration without updating the state state will make Terraform think it needs to create a new resource. The old resource still exists in the infrastructure, causing a conflict.

Please refer to Vinay B's answer or Moving resources for details on how to fix this issue.

Thank you for your answer. However, I'm getting this error, even if I run this script for the first time. No resources are being renamed or moved by hand. The issue is with the second (or in this case the first) association between the subnet and the network security group. I'm starting to wonder if this is a bug?

@s3b check if you're not creating duplicated resources by accident. search for the resource name or ID in the plan file. Also, run terraform code with an empty state file to see what happens.

That's what I'm trying to say: The error gets thrown even if I run this script   this first time, with an empty state file and within an empty ressource group. I invite you to run the script in my questions, it only has seven resources.

I now know what I did wrong. I assumed I need a NSG for each Virtual Machine. And I assumed that I can only have one subnet ressource for each NSG. That is wrong. One can only associate one subnet to one NSG. If you try to associate the already used subnet to a different NSG, this error happens.

@s3b that's correct: one subnet can be associated to one and only one NSG; but one NSG can be associated to multiple subnets.

Alright, then this has been solved. Thank you for your time.

@s3b np. Consider adding an answer to your own question - it might be useful to others that do the same mistake.
